# HessianConnectionException: 500: java.io.EOFException

Tags: android, spring, hessian, spring-remoting

I'm developing an Android application that communicates with a Hessian web service. It works fine after starting but when i call again the network function i get this error:

```
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170): Caused by: com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianConnectionException: 500: java.io.EOFException
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianProxy.invoke(HessianProxy.java:197)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at $Proxy2.getEventActionsCount(Native Method)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at com.example.hessian.EventServiceTask.doInBackground(EventServiceTask.java:69)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at com.example.hessian.EventServiceTask.doInBackground(EventServiceTask.java:1)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     ... 3 more
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170): Caused by: java.io.EOFException
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:573)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:821)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:495)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianProxy.invoke(HessianProxy.java:167)
08-21 14:27:24.712: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     ... 8 more
```

in my web app i'm using spring remoting 2.5 and Hessian 3.1, and in Android i'm using Hessdroid i download it from the net.

Comment: for more information my application works without exceptions on Android 2.3 but when i use Android 4.0 it doesen't work.

Comment: Finally i found the solution after many hours of search, the problem is that hessdroid is in version of Hessdroid so i use know flamingo and it works fine without exceptions.
this is the url to download it: http://exadel.org/flamingo